# Disabling Java huge-pages system-wide on a RH machine

Tags: java, huge-pages

I know I can disable Java's use of huge-pages for a process by adding

```
-XX:-UseLargePages
```

to the process invocation line.

However, I'd like to prevent **every** java application from using huge-pages, without me having to discover each process running on the machine.

Disabling THP in RH does not do it. Java still, by default, allocate memory from huge-pages even when THP is disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set this in the environment variable JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/envvars-138887.html for details

I checked this with my Eclipse installation. Before starting it I set the variable with `set JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dfoo=123 -Dbar=456"` (using `export` on the command line or setting it in the `environment` file will do the same trick on Linux).

Checking the JVM with visualvm shows that the new parameters are considered:
[image: VisualVM shows the set defines]

On the console or the corresponding logfile you will most likely see an entry like this:

> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: "-Dfoo=123 -Dbar=456"

Comment: Is this always possible or only when using JNI?

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find the delimiter for this variable, in case I wish to add several options. Is it ';'?

Comment: @howlingcat concat them with spaces